# Utility activities?

Tags: android

I'm a little confused about the naming conventions used here... but AFAIK it is possible to build an activity(?) that performs some small function than many different programs could use. For example a date-picker tool for use in a calendar or alarm program.

Fist of all I wish to know what these things are called. Where can I see a list of common ones that people expect on their phones pre-installed. And finally is it possible to make and distribute your own?

I had initially thought these things may be called widgets, but having had a look at a few of them, they appear to be complete programs in their own right - so I'm assuming that widget is not the word I'm looking for.

Comment: I have no idea why this got down-voted :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fist of all I wish to know what these things are called

There is no such concept in Android that meets all your requirements.

---

Here is my first interpretation of your points:

> For example a date-picker tool for use in a calendar or alarm program.

This is a widget.

> Where can I see a list of common ones that people expect on their phones pre-installed.

Users do not "expect" widgets, any more than they "expect" integers, `HashMap`s, or any other programming construct. The widgets that come "pre-installed" are the ones in the Android SDK.

> And finally is it possible to make and distribute your own?

You can certainly make your own custom widgets. You distribute them typically in the form of an Android library project, that other developers can download and link into their apps.

---

Here is my second interpretation of your points:

> AFAIK it is possible to build an activity(?) that performs some small function than many different programs could use... Fist of all I wish to know what these things are called

Activities.

> Where can I see a list of common ones that people expect on their phones pre-installed.

There is no such list. Any device can have any applications on it, at the combined discretion of the device manufacturer, mobile carrier (where relevant), and user. Any of those applications can export one or more activities that, in theory, other applications could link to.

That being said, you will find various `Intent` action strings in the Android SDK, particularly on the `Intent` class, that are designed to be used by `startActivity()`, and will be honored on most Android devices.

> And finally is it possible to make and distribute your own?

You are welcome to create an Android application. You are welcome to implement activities in that application. You are welcome to export those activities and give them action strings and the like. You are welcome to document those action strings and otherwise explain to third-party developers how they can invoke your activities. Also, you can create activities that support some of those common `Intent` actions I mentioned above (e.g., PDF viewer applications have activities that advertise that they can support viewing PDF files).